# Как сделать примерную проверку текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, искусственный-интеллект

У меня есть бот, он немного разговаривать умеет и мне нужно сделать чтобы когда я пишу например "Открой браузер" или "Запусти браузер" он должен запускать браузер. То есть мне нужно чтобы если запрос включает что-то похожее на "Открой браузер", браузер открывался.

Вот код самого бота если что:

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

# *** Создание матрицы ответов ***

#Объект преобразователя
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
#Объект таблицы
good = pd.read_csv('D:\My Code\Evgenia\Evgenia_mathonly\good.tsv', sep='\t')

#Обучение преобразователя
vectorizer.fit(good.context_0)

#Несжатая матрица
matrix_big = vectorizer.transform(good.context_0)
print('Матрица ответов создана')



# *** Сжатие матрицы ***

#Проекция данных в n-мерное пространство
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10) #Чем больше значение, тем больше точность ответа

svd.fit(matrix_big)
matrix_small = svd.transform(matrix_big)
print('Сжатие матрицы завершено')



# *** Выбор ответа ***

def softmax(x):
    proba = np.exp(-x)
    return proba / sum(proba)

class NeighborSampler(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, k=5, temperature=1.0):
        self.k = k
        self.temperature = temperature
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.tree_ = BallTree(X)
        self.y_ = np.array(y)
    def predict(self, X, random_state=None):
        distances, indices = self.tree_.query(X, return_distance=True, k=self.k)
        result = []
        for distance, index in zip(distances, indices):
            result.append(np.random.choice(index, p=softmax(distance * self.temperature)))
        return self.y_[result]



# *** Соединение ***

ns = NeighborSampler()
ns.fit(matrix_small, good.reply)
pipe = make_pipeline(vectorizer, svd, ns)
print('Сборка компонентов завершена')
print('Запускаюсь...')
print(' ')



# *** Обработка ответа ***

print('Приветик!')

while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == 'Откорой браузер':
        os.system('C:/Users/fox/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera/launcher.exe')
        print('Открываю Opera')
    elif inp == 'Открой Эдж':
        # os.system('C:/ProgramFiles(x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe')
        print('Эта функция не работает на данный момент')
    elif inp == 'Стоп':
        print('Отключение...')
        exit()
    else:
        print(pipe.predict([inp]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не такая простая тема. И ответ зависит от того, готовы вы сами найти перечислить все синонимы типа открыть/запустить/... или вы хотите, чтобы за вас это сделала ваша модель.

Ну, первый вариант не сложен - вам нужно пройтись по введённой фразе, перебрать в ней все слова, в ещё одном цикле перебрать синонимы и если совпадение найдётся, то значит делаем действие. Просто цикл в цикле. Ну, плюс приведение к одному регистру всех слов, конечно.

Второй вариант требует совсем другого подхода - вам нужно будет использовать модель Word2Vec или Doc2Vec, для этого либо взять готовую тренированную модель либо натренировать свою модель такого типа на большом корпусе подходящих текстов. Word2Vec должен быть способен сам разобраться, что словосочетания "открыть браузер" и "запустить браузер" встречаются в похожих контекстах, а значит они будут лежать близко в пространстве векторов этой модели. Так что проверяем примерно тем же методом, что и в первом варианте, но сравниваем не слова, а близость векторов слов.